# Check locale of admin user Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Is there a way to programmatically get the language of the admin user that is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

To acheive this you would need to do something like this

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class View extends Template
{
    protected $authSession;
    public function __construct(Session $authSession)
    {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser();
    }
    /** 
     * This should return back the users locale 
     */
    public function getUserLocale()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentUser()->getInterfaceLocale();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this-

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;
class LocaleLanguage extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerRepoInfterface;
    protected $authSession;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context  $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    )
    {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

   

    public function getAdminUserLocale()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentAdminUser()->getInterfaceLocale();
    }

    public function getCurrentAdminUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser();
    }

  


}
```

**May be it is helping you.**